# JavaFX Sliders not following increment values?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on the UI for my Wireworld (Conway's Game of Life variant) clone, and I've run into some weird behavior with the sliders controlling the width and height of the game grid. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this.

I have a check box in my UI that allows me to "lock dimensions", meaning that while it's checked, regardless of which slider you drag, they will each have the same value (ie: if you drag one to a value of 50, the other will be dragged to 50 as well). This has caused some strange behavior though. I have specifically set block increments, as well as the minor tick count and the major tick unit -- but when I lock dimensions, it ignores the increments I set and snaps to the wrong numbers.

Here is the code where I setup the two sliders...

```
cellsWideSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
cellsWideSlider.setMajorTickUnit(50);
cellsWideSlider.setMinorTickCount(1);
cellsWideSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
cellsWideSlider.setBlockIncrement(10);
cellsWideSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val) {
        cwl.setText("Cells Wide: " + (int)new_val.doubleValue());
        if(lockToggle.isSelected()) {
            cellsHighSlider.setValue(new_val.doubleValue());
            chl.setText("Cells High: " + (int)new_val.doubleValue());
        }
        resizeGrid((int)cellsWideSlider.getValue(), (int)cellsHighSlider.getValue());
    }
});
propbar.getChildren().add(cellsWideSlider);

cellsHighSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
cellsHighSlider.setMajorTickUnit(50);
cellsHighSlider.setMinorTickCount(1);
cellsHighSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
cellsHighSlider.setBlockIncrement(10);
cellsHighSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val) {
        chl.setText("Cells High: " + (int)new_val.doubleValue());
        if(lockToggle.isSelected()) {
            cellsWideSlider.setValue(new_val.doubleValue());
            cwl.setText("Cells Wide: " + (int)new_val.doubleValue());
        }
        resizeGrid((int)cellsWideSlider.getValue(), (int)cellsHighSlider.getValue());
    }
});
propbar.getChildren().add(cellsHighSlider);
```

Has anyone encountered this behavior before? Does it have something to do with the way I'm "locking" them together?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I copied your code and it always snapped to tick marks (multiples of 25) regardless of whether or not it was locked. Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Yes... that's the problem. The block increment is 10, not 25... it should snap to every 10 value.

Comment: No, it is `snapToTicks`, not `snapToBlockIncrements`. (You could argue that the `snapTo` value should be independent of the `tick` values, as one is behavior and one is displayed; but they're not.) If you want it to snap to every 10 (with the other values you have), use `setMinorTickCount(4)`.

Comment: But none of those tick values is set to 25, so I don't get why it's snapping to multiples of 25.

Comment: Because that's where the tick marks are. Just a question: have you actually read the documentation for the properties you are setting? E.g. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#snapToTicksProperty), or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#minorTickCountProperty)? They are pretty clear.

Comment: Yes, I know what snapToTicks does, but I think minorTickCount is what's confusing me. It just clicked that it's essentially dividing the majorTickUnit to create spaces. I realized that by putting one minor tick in between two major ticks, that divides the major tick gap of 50 into 2, giving 25.

Comment: Well, that's what I get for blindly following a tutorial. This is the first JavaFX application I've made.

Comment: Ah, yes. Any time you're learning from a tutorial, browsing some of the javadocs for the classes and methods it uses will greatly help understand how the tutorial code is working.